# Vertical center align text with icon (update)

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I'm having a problem vertically aligning two icons with a text element. I'm unsure as to why the text div is creating an extra space above its container. How do I vertical align the two text lines with the two checkbox icons?

- I just realized that the space above the p tag is being generated by the image. When I set the positioning of the image to absolute, the text and image align.

Here is a link to the website: http://fosterinnovationculture.com/email/index.html

Here is a screenshot of the misaligned icons:[image]

Here is the HTML:

```
<th style="text-align:center">
     <div class="bullet-container">
          <div class="bullet-one">
               <div class="img-left" style="width:60px; margin:0; display:inline-block; text-align:right;">
                    <img src="images/icons/check_box.png" style="width:30px; display:inline-block; margin-right:0px">
               </div>
               <div class="content-right" style="display:inline-block">
                    <p>Remove all work, supplies, and trash</p>
               </div>
          </div>
    </div>
</th>
```

Comment: Try giving your images `vertical-align: middle`

Comment: God, I didn't even know vertical-align middle existed. Thanks!

Comment: @marcos vertical-align alone wont handle this. Check my answer I tested it in the browser and it works! Just paste my css into your css file and then replace the html with the html in my answer.

Comment: So I just realized that the '<img>' tag is creating a horizontal line space because when I set the position to absolute, the text inside the p tag aligns with the image. @loktar

Comment: Do not set it to absolute. That is going to cause you more problems even if it looks like it fixed something right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just checked in your website,

Add this class to your css then add the class to the p tag inside the table you want to vertically algin center

```
.text-align-vert {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 4px;
}
```

Then inside your html

```
<th style="text-align:center">
     <div class="bullet-container">
          <div class="bullet-one">
               <div class="img-left" style="width:60px; margin:0; display:inline-block; text-align:right;">
                    <img src="images/icons/check_box.png" style="width:30px; display:inline-block; margin-right:0px">
               </div>
               <div class="content-right" style="display:inline-block">
                    <p class="text-align-vert">Remove all work, supplies, and trash</p>
               </div>
          </div>
    </div>
</th>
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @wuno, why did 'display: table-cell' work? What does display: table-cell do?

Comment: @marcos it makes the p tag in your case behave like td. td is where your putting data in the table rows tr. The fact that you were wrapping a p tag in the table was making it act dumb. table-cell Let the element behave like a <td> element. Let me know if you need anything else. If my answer helped you please accept it! :)

Comment: Adding padding will fit the UI for a single line only. If the line runs through multiple lines it will add padding to all the multiple lines.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your classes with these styles. I think this will fix the styles for you.

```
.bullet-one {
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.img-left {
    width: 60px;
    margin: 0;
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: right;
}

.content-right {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.content-right p {
    margin: 0;
}
```

I have attached the updated style screenshot.

[image]